# Restrict requests from a certain domain with parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to restrict requests on Parse.com to a certain domain (i.e. the hosting domain)?

The request in question is a cloud function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ip address as part of the request object. You can apply a filter in cloud code to allow request from certain ip otherwise send 401 Unauthorized Request http code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do I get this IP ? 
In the docs, they say that the following about the request object:
request - The request object contains information about the request. The following fields are set:
params - The parameters object sent to the function by the client.
user - The Parse.User that is making the request. This will not be set if there was no logged-in user.